# bootstrap css element style change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created simple page structure (responsive) to learn bootstrap. I have few issue.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/3uwaR/1/

1. I want to set color of line in page-header as `27ae60` (the line below Get purified text)
2. In right side panel I want to put horizontal line between page content and menu items
3. I wanted to set container border width and color
               border-color: red !important;
               border-bottom-width: 1px !important;

but it does not affect.

So I added another div with class `nice` and added css. why still no effect?

css:

```
.container
            {
                margin: 2% !important;
                font-family: calibri !important;
                font-size: 115%;
                margin: 2%;
                border-color: red !important;
                border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            }
            .nice 
            {
                margin: 2%;
                border-color: red !important;
                border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                border-width:2px;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CSS syntax:

```
border: [border-width || border-style || border-color] | inherit
```

So just try add border like this:

```
border: 1px solid red !important;
```

Also you can use:

```
border-top:1px solid red;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
border-left:1px solid grey;
border-right:1px solid brown;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uwaR/3/)

Comment: thanks dude, why top margin in red border is not appearing? do you have any idea about point 1 and 2?